# Hibernate Table_Per_Class Inheritance query

Tags: java, hibernate

Say 1 have this simple structure

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = Table_Per_Class)
class A {
@Id
private a;
private b;
}

@Entity
class B extends A{
private c;
}

@Entity
class C extends A{
private d;
}
```

Now :

Class A member varibles are private , meaning they wont be inherited by Class B and Class C . Speaking other way , B and C class wont be having a separate copy of a and b. Even then we can see that Hibernate creates separate column ( and values ) for a and b in the B and C Tables in databses. I am not able to understand this part . Please help me out .

Answer (score 0):

B extends A. So B is a A. Since A has `a` and `b` fields, B also has them.

The state of an object is made of the set of fields it has, plus the set of fields its superclass has, plus the set of fields of the superclass of the superclass, etc. And this has nothing to do with Hibernate.

If a fruit has a color, and if a banana is a fruit, a banana has a color. Since Hibernate persists the state of the banana, it has to persists its color. The fact that the color field is private in Fruit doesn't make any difference.

Comment: But its a well known fact that private fields are not inherited.. even java specification says that .. isn't ?

Comment: They can't be accessed by the subclass, but they are part of the state of subclass instances. A Fruit doesn't make sense without its color, so a banana doesn't make sense without it. How would a public `getColor()` method (returning the private color field of the fruit) work if invoked on a banana if banana doesn't have the field in its state?